# Cassandra TimeUUID in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, timeuuid

I am migrating an application from Cassandra to DynamoDB. On Cassandra we used as key a combination of (entityName,TimeUUID), with DynamoDB as far as I have read I could use a Hash+Range Primary Key.

To mantain the same data structure of the Cassandra Database I have been thinking of using entityName as Hash and timestamp as range. Then, I thought that maybe the timestamps might not be Unique: I am speaking of corner cases, but the Cassandra Primary Key (entityName,TimeUUID) is more powerful than the DynamoDB Hash+Range (entityName, timestamp), since it allows the existence of elements with the same entityName and timestamp.

Can I use Cassandra's TimeUUID as DynamoDb's range? Are there any reason why I should not use this approach?

Comment: You might also consider asking/moving this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should, if you think you can have collisions on `timestamp`). The only catch, I can think of, is that you might have to handle `between time_x and time_y` `Query` on your own.

For e.g., let's say you have these 5 items in your table:

- HK: `h1`. RK: `t1_uuid1`
- HK: `h1`. RK: `t1_uuid2`
- HK: `h1`. RK: `t2_uuid3`
- HK: `h1`. RK: `t3_uuid4`
- HK: `h2`. RK: `t4_uuid5`

Also, assume that `t1` < `t2` < `t3` and UUIDs are 4 character strings between `aaaa` and `zzzz`

Now, if you need all items with HK `h1` and RK between `t1` and `t2`, then your `Query` would contain something like `between t1_aaaa and t2_zzzz`.

This is because DynamoDB does not, on its own, understand the concept of TimeUUIDs like Cassandra. So, you'll have to handle cases such as above in your application layer.